# Smarty - foreach loop 4 times and create a new list

Tags: php, html, smarty

I want to achieve a list like this with smarty.

```
<ul>
 <li>
   <a>img1</a>
   <a>img2</a>
   <a>img3</a>
   <a>img4</a>
 </li>
 <li>
   <a>img5</a>
   <a>img6</a>
   <a>img7</a>
   <a>img8</a>
 </li>
<li>
   <a>img9</a>
   <a>img10</a>
   <a>img11</a>
   <a>img12</a>
 </li>
</ul>
```

Using this sample code

```
<ul class="bullet">
    {foreach from=$manufacturers item=manufacturer name=manufacturer_list}
        {if $smarty.foreach.manufacturer_list.index < 4}
      <li class="{if $smarty.foreach.manufacturer_list.last}last_item{elseif $smarty.foreach.manufacturer_list.first}first_item{else}item{/if}">   

        <a href="{$link->getmanufacturerLink($manufacturer.id_manufacturer, $manufacturer.link_rewrite)}" title="{l s='More about' mod='blockmanufacturer'}{$manufacturer.name}"> <img src="{$img_manu_dir}{$manufacturer.id_manufacturer}.jpg"><span>{$manufacturer.name}<span></a>
      </li>
    {/if}
{/foreach}
```

First with given array $manufacturers it will loop inside a `<li>` max of 4 times and will create 4 `<img>`. And then, when it reach the 4th index, it will make a new `<li>` tag.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Im Smarty3 syntax you could do something like:

```
{$data = [
    "alpha", "bravo", "charlie", "delta", "echo", "foxtrot", "golf", 
    "hotel", "india", "juliet", "kilo", "lima", "mike", "november", 
    "oscar", "papa", "quebec", "romeo", "sierra", "tango", "uniform", 
    "victor", "whiskey", "x-ray", "yankee", "zulu"
]}

{foreach $data as $value}
  {if $value@first}
    <ul>
      <li>
  {elseif ($value@iteration - 1) is div by 4}
      </li><li>
  {/if}

  <span>{$value}</span>

  {if $value@last}
      </li>
    </ul>
  {/if}
{/foreach}
```

Note that because of nesting the whole `<ul>` within the foreach loop, it would not show if there was no data to loop over.

Comment: `iteration - 1` why not just use index?

Comment: Because you could be iterating a map (associative array / string keys) which wouldn't work for index.

Answer (score 5):

You want display 4 images in every li tag?

```
<ul>
{foreach from=$manufacturers item=manufacturer name=manufacturer_list}
  {if $smarty.foreach.manufacturer_list.index % 4 == 0}
    <li>
  {/if}

  <a><img></a>

  {if $smarty.foreach.manufacturer_list.index % 4 == 0 || $smarty.foreach.manufacturer_list.last}
    </li>
  {/if}
{/foreach}
</ul>
```